# Django and DB error "Column 'id' specified twice"

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am new to django and I am having some issues when I try to save a mapping.

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Users(models.Model):
        user = models.CharField(max_length=45)
        password = models.CharField(max_length=125)
        env = models.CharField(max_length=10)
        class Meta:
                db_table = 'esp-users'
        def __unicode__(self):
                return unicode(self.user)
class Groups(models.Model):
        group_name = models.CharField(max_length=45)
        description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        env = models.CharField(max_length=45)
        class Meta:
                db_table = 'esp-groups'
        def __unicode__(self):
                return unicode(self.group_name)
class Roles(models.Model):
        role_name = models.CharField(max_length=45)
        env = models.CharField(max_length=10)
        class Meta:
                db_table = 'esp-roles'
        def __unicode__(self):
                return unicode(self.role_name)
class Group_Map(models.Model):
        group_id = models.ForeignKey(Groups, db_column='id')
        user_id = models.ForeignKey(Users, db_column='id')
        class Meta:
                db_table='esp-group-map'
        def __unicode__(self):
                return unicode(self.group_id)
class Role_Map(models.Model):
        role_id = models.ForeignKey(Roles, db_column='id')
        group_id = models.ForeignKey(Groups, db_column='id')
        class Meta:
                db_table='esp-role-map'
        def __unicode__(self):
                return unicode(self.role_id)
```

Thanks for the help.

Django V 1.3, Python 2.4, Mysql 5.0.77

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://somehost:8100/admin/users_admin/group_map/add/
Django Version:     1.3
Exception Type:     DatabaseError
Exception Value:

(1110, "Column 'id' specified twice")

Lesson Learned: If its a new database isntead of making the tables yourself just run python manage.py syncdb and it will make the db for you and all is good. Thanks for the help!

Comment: The [SOLVED] prefix is unnecessary. Users can see whether you have accepted an answer or not by the colour of the number beside your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't do this:

```
group_id = models.ForeignKey(Groups, db_column='id')
user_id = models.ForeignKey(Users, db_column='id')
```

You just need to do:

```
group_id = models.ForeignKey(Groups)
user_id = models.ForeignKey(Users)
```

Django will infer what column to use based on `Users` and `Groups` primary keys.

While you are at it, I would recommend you to change `Groups` into `Group`, `Users` into `User` and so on, so forth. Your code will be more clear since you will do stuff like:

```
user = User()
```

Instead of:

```
user = Users()
```

Comment: might be helpful to add how to explicitly specify the target column

Comment: I tried to do that and I got an error complaining that it could not find group_id_id so I had to use the db_column to make it work.

Comment: Did Django generate the tables for you?

Comment: No I made the tables I didnt know django could do that. But I get this Exception Value:  

(1054, "Unknown column 'group_id_id' in 'field list'")

Comment: If you made the tables, then you need to provide DJANGO with the column names. What's your Users model primary key? DJANGO documentation is pretty good. So you might want to read a little bit about models (and how Django handles them) before continuing...

Comment: why to add  "_id" at the end? django will add it automatically for ForeignKey

Comment: yea I saw that if I did a manage.py syncdb it would create the tables for me and that worked fine. So I just needed to do that way instead of specifying.

Answer (score 1):

```
group = models.ForeignKey(Groups, db_column='group_id')
user = models.ForeignKey(Users, db_column='user_id')
```

Answer (score 0):

You are specifying `db_column='id'` for both `group_id` and for `user_id`. You can't have two columns with the same name. You can remove this parameter and let Django take care of the naming for you.

Answer (score 0):

`db_column` specifies the column name to use in the model you're defining, not the referred one. There is no need to specify column names for FKs, it's done automatically.